# R function to perform ANOVA and TukeyHSD from Sample Mean, SD, and n

Tags: r, statistics, anova

I wonder if there is any R function to perform ANOVA and TukeyHSD from Sample Mean, SD, and Sample Size (n). I found `ind.oneway.second` function from `rpsychi` to perform ANOVA on Sample Statistics but could not find any function to perform TukeyHSD on Sample Statistics.

```
library("rpsychi")

Mean <- c(90,85,92,100,102,106)
SD <- c(9.035613,11.479667,9.760268,7.662572,9.830258,9.111457)
SampleSize <- c(9,9,9,9,9,9)

fm1 <- ind.oneway.second(Mean, SD, SampleSize)
fm1
names(fm1)
TukeyHSD(fm1$anova.table)
```

Comment: I was working on a package that would do something like this.  It had a function that mimicked ind.oneway.second in that it performed anova solely on sample means, sds, and sample sizes.  It also returned an actual lm object and some simulated data if desired.  That should be enough to proceed with what you want I would think.  I'm not at home at the moment so I don't have that code available but if there is interest I could whip it together and actually get it on CRAN shortly (obviously I could put it on github in the meantime).

Comment: That would be great @Dason. Looking forward for your answer. Thanks

Comment: With that said I'm looking forward to seeing if somebody else already has done something similar on CRAN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work.  Basically it just simulates data that exactly matches the given means, standard deviations, and sample sizes.  After that you can fit the model of interest and do any post hoc tests that you're interested in.

```
Mean <- c(90,85,92,100,102,106)
SD <- c(9.035613,11.479667,9.760268,7.662572,9.830258,9.111457)
SampleSize <- c(9,9,9,9,9,9)


gen_data <- function(means, sds, samplesizes){
  n.grp <- length(means)
  grps <- factor(rep(1:n.grp, samplesizes))
  dat <- lapply(1:n.grp, function(i) {scale(rnorm(samplesizes[i]))*sds[i] + means[i]})
  y <- do.call(rbind, dat)
  out <- data.frame(group = grps, y = y)
  out
}

simulated_data <- gen_data(Mean, SD,SampleSize)
av <- aov(y ~ group, data = simulated_data)
summary(av)
TukeyHSD(av)
```

Comment: You missed `.grp` after `n` inside the `lapply`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I get for not checking it in a clean R session